# SSM Send Command Failed,Is it possible to run ssm command from one aws account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, aws-ssm

I have the Jenkins node in **Account A** that builds the angular application
For Deploying the dist folder I need to copy files from s3 to the angular instance.
But the angular Instance is in **Account B**

**Script:**

aws --region us-west-2 ssm send-command
--instance-ids i-xxxxxx --document-name AWS-RunShellScript
--comment 'Deployment from Pipeline xxx-release-pipeline'
--cloud-watch-output-config 'CloudWatchOutputEnabled=true,CloudWatchLogGroupName=SSMDocumentRunLogGroup'
--parameters '{"commands":["aws --region us-west-2 s3 cp s3://xxxx/dist/*.zip /var/www/demo.com/html", "unzip -q *.zip"]}'
--output text --query Command.CommandId

So when I run ssm send-command from node(in Account A) it shows Invalid Instance Id.

**An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation**

Jenkins node -> Account A
Angular Instance(with ssm agent) -> Account B

In the pipeline for deploy stage I need to copy files from s3 to instance in Account B
Is there a way to implement this use case in a better way with or without ssm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can directly run `run-command` accross account. But you could run in through [AWS Systems Manager Automation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-automation.html). In your automation document you can use [aws:runCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-runcommand.html).

This is possible because SSM Automation [supports cross-account and cross-region deployments](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/managing-aws-resources-across-multiple-accounts-and-regions-using-aws-systems-manager-automation/).

Comment: Yes I am trying with send-command,Please have a look at the script section I have mentioned.

Comment: @Kevin You could do it through automation.